# Recovering admin password in collabnet svn

Tags: svn, collabnet

I followed the instructions at [how to recover root password in Collabnet SVN Edge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9921317/how-to-recover-root-password-in-collabnet-svn-edge) and successfully reset my admin password. However, when I restart the Edge service a second time, it reverts back to the old (forgotten) admin password. In addition, a user that I deleted reappears! I'm assuming that something is editing the csvn-production-hsqldb.script file behind the scenes and when it restarts, it restores everything to what it was before.
Unfortunately I can't add this as a comment to the original question as I don't have 50 reputation points yet :-(

Thanks

Joe